# Implementing a Shell in C: Output redirection is writing output file name to output file rather than command results

Tags: c

I'm implementing a shell in C with input and output redirection. I can successfully do input redirection, but output redirection will not work. For instance, if I do `ls > out.txt`, out.txt contains the text "out.txt" rather than the results of the `ls` command.

I have looked at other stack overflow answers and the open() and creat() documentation, but have not been able to solve the problem.

This is the code I currently have if an output redirection (>) is detected:

```
if(outRedirect == 1)
{
   //I have tried using open() and creat()
   //int out = open(args[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0640);
   int out = creat(args[1], 0640);
   dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
   close(out);
   //reset flag to 0
   outRedirect = 0;
   //execute command
   execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

I want the out.txt file to contain:

```
a.out
in.txt
makefile
out.txt
README
simple-shell
simple-shell.c
```

but it contains

```
out.txt
```

Comment: Since you are running `ls`, is `out.txt` also not the output? Do you have any other files in the directory?

Comment: You have to remove the redirection text from the command line.  Commands don’t get to see any of the redirection done by the shell.  The chances are you’re asking to list the file into the file.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya out.txt is the output file, but the results of the ls command should be written to out.txt. I do have other files in the directory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you mean I have to remove the redirection text from the command line?

Comment: You must make sure that when your shell executes `ls > out.txt`, neither the `>` nor the `out.txt` are passed to `ls`.  I suspect that you’re passing the file name.  At least, it is an explanation for why you see the file name in the output file.

Comment: @LindseyPiggott I think the command you are finally executing is `ls out.txt`. Like Jonathan said, you are not removing the second argument. This causes `ls` to just print `out.txt` (since it is in the directory) and that is all that goes into the out put

Comment: Thank you both! That ended up being my issue.

Comment: Minor nit: you are implementing a shell in C.  "C shell" generally refers to the family of shells including tcsh and csh.

Comment: @LindseyPiggott If that's the case, please answer your own question or ask somebody else to answer it and accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring relevant comments into an answer.*</sup>

You have to remove the redirection text from the command line. Commands don’t get to see any of the redirection done by the shell. The chances are you’re asking to list the file into the file.

> What do you mean I "have to remove the redirection text from the command line"?

You must make sure that when your shell executes `ls > out.txt`, neither the `>` nor the `out.txt` are passed to `ls`. I suspect that you’re passing the file name. At least, it is an explanation for why you see (only) the file name in the output file.

And as [Ajay Brahmakshatriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858773/ajay-brahmakshatriya) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658154/implementing-a-shell-in-c-output-redirection-is-writing-output-file-name-to-out/55659380#comment98005538_55658154):

> I think the command you are finally executing is `ls out.txt`. Like Jonathan said, you are not removing the second argument. This causes `ls` to just print `out.txt` (since it is in the directory) and that is all that goes into the output.

---

> Thank you both! That ended up being my issue.